# Convert Spark DataFrame to Pojo Object

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Please see below code:

```
    //Create Spark Context
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestWithObjects").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    //Creating RDD
    JavaRDD<Person> personsRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(persons);
    //Creating SQL context
    SQLContext sQLContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);
    DataFrame personDataFrame = sQLContext.createDataFrame(personsRDD, Person.class);
    personDataFrame.show();
    personDataFrame.printSchema();
    personDataFrame.select("name").show();
    personDataFrame.registerTempTable("peoples");
    DataFrame result = sQLContext.sql("SELECT * FROM peoples WHERE name='test'");
    result.show();
```

After this I need to convert the DataFrame - 'result' to Person Object or List. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

DataFrame is simply a type alias of Dataset[Row] . These operations are also referred as “untyped transformations” in contrast to “typed transformations” that come with strongly typed Scala/Java Datasets.

The conversion from Dataset[Row] to Dataset[Person] is very simple in spark

`DataFrame result = sQLContext.sql("SELECT * FROM peoples WHERE name='test'");`

At this point, Spark converts your data into DataFrame = Dataset[Row], a collection of generic Row object, since it does not know the exact type.

```
// Create an Encoders for Java beans
Encoder<Person> personEncoder = Encoders.bean(Person.class); 
Dataset<Person> personDF = result.as(personEncoder);
personDF.show();
```

Now, Spark converts the Dataset[Row] -> Dataset[Person] type-specific Scala / Java  JVM object, as dictated by the class Person.

Please refer to below link provided by  databricks for further details

https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

Comment: It seems the encoder tries to set all the class parameters not only those that are in constructor.
For example if I have a class like
`class A {
    int p1
    int p2 

    public A(int p1) {
        this.p1 = p1 
        this.p2 = p1 * 2  
   }
}`

int the above case, the encoder asks for both p1 and p2 to be available in the dataframe which is odd.

Answer (score 2):

A `DataFrame` is stored as `Row`s, so you can use [the methods there to cast from untyped to typed](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html). Take a look at the `get` methods.

Comment: As the methods give, we can only get each value by value but not as a whole object

Comment: @DonMathew And you won't get anything better at this point. You can convert to JSON and go from there if it is easier. Upcoming `DataSet` API should give you more or less what you want, although I am not sure if POJOs won't require decoders right now.

Answer (score 2):

If someone looking for **conversion of json string column** in `Dataset<Row>` to `Dataset<PojoClass>`

**Sample pojo: Testing**

```
@Data
public class Testing implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String dept;
}
```

In the above code `@Data` is an annotation from Lombok to generate getters and setters for this `Testing` class.

**Actual conversion logic in Spark**

```
@Test
void shouldConvertJsonStringToPojo() {
   var sparkSession  = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate(); 
   var structType =  new StructType(new StructField[] {
        new StructField("employee", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
    });

    var ds = sparkSession.createDataFrame(new ArrayList<>(
        Arrays.asList(RowFactory.create(new Object[]{"{ \"name\": \"test\", \"dept\": \"IT\"}"}))), structType);

    var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var bean = Encoders.bean(Testing.class);

    var testingDataset = ds.map((MapFunction<Row, Testing>) row -> {
        var dept = row.<String>getAs("employee");

        return objectMapper.readValue(dept, Testing.class);
    }, bean);

    assertEquals("test", testingDataset.head().getName());
}
```