# How to convert messages from socket streaming source to custom domain object?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm very new to spark streaming. I have a Spark Standalone 2.2 running with one worker. I'm using a socket source and trying to read the incoming stream into an object called MicroserviceMessage.

```scala
val message = spark.readStream
  .format("socket")
  .option("host", host)
  .option("port", port)
  .load()

val df = message.as[MicroserviceMessage].flatMap(microserviceMessage =>
    microserviceMessage.DataPoints.map(datapoint => (datapoint, microserviceMessage.ServiceProperties, datapoint.EpochUTC)))
  .toDF("datapoint", "properties", "timestamp")
```

I'm hoping this will a DataFrame with columns of "datapoint", "properties" and "timestamp"

The data i'm pasting into my netcat terminal looks like this (this is what I'm trying to read in as MicroserviceMessage):

```scala
{
  "SystemType": "mytype",
  "SystemGuid": "6c84fb90-12c4-11e1-840d-7b25c5ee775a",
  "TagType": "Raw Tags",
  "ServiceType": "FILTER",
  "DataPoints": [
    {
      "TagName": "013FIC003.PV",
      "EpochUTC": 1505247956001,
      "ItemValue": 25.47177,
      "ItemValueStr": "NORMAL",
      "Quality": "Good",
      "TimeOffset": "P0000"
    },
    {
      "TagName": "013FIC003.PV",
      "EpochUTC": 1505247956010,
      "ItemValue": 26.47177,
      "ItemValueStr": "NORMAL",
      "Quality": "Good",
      "TimeOffset": "P0000"
    }
  ],
  "ServiceProperties": [
    {
      "Key": "OutputTagName",
      "Value": "FI12102.PV_CL"
    },
    {
      "Key": "OutputTagType",
      "Value": "Cleansing Flow Tags"
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead what I see is:

```scala
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`SystemType`' given input columns: [value];
```

MicroserviceMessage case class looks like this:

```scala
case class DataPoints
(
  TagName: String,
  EpochUTC: Double,
  ItemValue: Double,
  ItemValueStr: String,
  Quality: String,
  TimeOffset: String
)

case class ServiceProperties
(
  Key: String,
  Value: String
)

case class MicroserviceMessage
(
  SystemType: String,
  SystemGuid: String,
  TagType: String,
  ServiceType: String,
  DataPoints: List[DataPoints],
  ServiceProperties: List[ServiceProperties]
)
```

EDIT:
After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194019/convert-spark-dataframe-to-pojo-object) I was able to start the job by doing

```scala
val messageEncoder = Encoders.bean(classOf[MicroserviceMessage])

val df = message.select($"value").as(messageEncoder).map(
  msmg => (msmg.ServiceType, msmg.SystemGuid)
).toDF("service", "guid")
```

But this causes issues when I start sending data.

```scala
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize
```

Full [stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/PBjT3nav)

Comment: _"The data i'm pasting into my netcat terminal looks like this (this is what I'm trying to read in as MicroserviceMessage):"_ <-- if you're pasting using the multi-line JSON you will get every single line of the copied content as separate lines and hence you'll break the input and stream processing afterwards.

Comment: How do you start your Spark Structured Streaming application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the exception

> Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize

is that you compiled your Spark Structured Streaming application using Scala 2.12.4 (or any other in 2.12 stream) which is unsupported in Spark 2.2.

From the scaladoc of [scala.runtime.LambdaDeserializer](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/runtime/LambdaDeserializer$.html):

> This class is only intended to be called by synthetic $deserializeLambda$ method that the Scala 2.12 compiler will add to classes hosting lambdas.

Spark 2.2 supports up to and including Scala 2.11.12 with 2.11.8 being the most "blessed" version.

Comment: This was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
message.as[MicroserviceMessage]
```

is incorrect as explained by the error message:

> cannot resolve '`SystemType`' given input columns: [value];

Data that comes from `SocketStream` is just string (or string and timestamp). To make it usable for strongly typed `Dataset` you have to parse it, for example with `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
I think i got past that issue by following this post 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194019/convert-spark-dataframe-to-pojo-object) which lets me start the job but as soon as I send data; I see a big long stacktrace with 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize