# May I convert a RDD<POJO> to a Dataframe a way I can write these POJOs in a table having the same attributes names than the POJO?

Tags: java, apache-spark

According to a reply made to [Convert Spark DataFrame to Pojo Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194019/convert-spark-dataframe-to-pojo-object) I've learn that a `Dataframe` is an alias of `Dataset<Row>`.

I currently calculated a `JavaPairRDD<CityCode, CityStatistics>` where `CityStatistics` is a POJO containing getters and setters for members like : `getCityCode()`, `getCityName()`, `getActivityCode()`, `getNumberOfSalaried()`, `getNumberOfCompanies()`...

A `Liquibase` script has created a statistics table where those fields (`CITYCODE`, `CITYNAME`, `ACTIVITYCODE`...) exist. I just have to write the records.

What is the (or before that : is there any) clean way to do something like that from my `JavaPairRDD<CityCode, CityStatistics> citiesStatisticsRDD` ?
`citiesStatisticsRDD.values()` => `DataSet<CityStatistics>` => `DataSet<Row> (= DataFrame)` => write on a JDBC connection through a dataframe method ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to convert JavaPairRDD to RDD beacuse `.createDataset() accepts RDD<T> not JavaRDD<T>`.`JavaRDD` is a wrapper around RDD inorder to make calls from java code easier. It contains RDD internally and can be accessed using .rdd()

```
JavaRDD cityRDD = citiesStatisticsRDD.map(x -> x._2);
Dataset<CityStatistics> cityDS =  sqlContext.createDataset(cityRDD.rdd(), Encoders.bean(CityStatistics.class))
```

Now if you want whole citiesStatisticsRDD converted to Dataset: Convert JavaPairRDD to RDD and then use encoders

```
Dataset<Row> cityDS = sqlContext.createDataset(citiesStatisticsRDD.values().rdd(), Encoders.bean(CityStatistics.class)).toDF();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But how are table columns set in the Dataset<Row> eventually created ? Shouldn't I call `.toDF("CITYCODE", "CITYNAME", "ACTIVITYCODE", ...)` instead of `.toDF("key", "value")` ? At the end, I want to end my operation by a `cityDS.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option(...)
  .save();`. Will it work ? I can't figure how the mapping is done between the `Dataset<CityStatistics>` and the `Dataset<Row>` : how .toDF() do the matching beetween pojo getter methods names and table column names.

Comment: Here ("key","value") will work as root columns in dataframe schema. We are already providing the encoders for columns no need to do that. You can just use `toDF()` .